# Hiding Forms and then showing on click on link issue

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a **link** called **"advanced search section"** for my website which will be will show additional options for my search which will be hidden until the user clicks on the advanced search link.

For some reason everything is already displayed. I've been trying this for a while and searching the web with no solution.

I'm fairly new to `jquery` so I'm not too sure if i am doing this right but here is my code:

**`index.php` code** :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#filter').hide();
});

$('body').on('click','nav a', function(e) {
    $('#filter').show();
    $('#filter').children().hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    e.preventDefault();
});​
</script>

</head>

<body>
<?php include_once("access_toppage.php"); ?>
<div id="middlepage">

    <div id="mainSearchArea">
        <form action="search.php" id="mainSearch" name="searchForm" method="POST">
            <input type="search" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
            <select id"changes" name="change">
            <option value="">All Categories </option>
            <option value="Yatch">Yatch </option>
            <option value="Motor">Motor </option>
            <option value="Dingy">Dingy </option>
            <option value="Transport">Transport </option>
            <option value="Recreational">Recreational </option>

            </select>
            <input type="submit" id="go" value="Search">




    <nav>
        <a href="#filter">Advanced Search</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="filter">       
        <div id="city">
            <select id="city" name="city">
            <option value =""> All Cities</option>
            <option value="Dover">Dover </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

**`css` code** :

```
.hide {
display:none;
}

#filter
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest there isn't any reason why it wouldn't be hidden.  However, I believe you may have a character at the end of your javascript code that you just can't see.

See my jsfiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dklingman/2prQ7/)**.  This was copied directly from what you have above.  Notice the little red dot at the end of the code.

Now look at this fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dklingman/88N4A/4/)**.  Notice the red dot is gone and the drop down is hidden.

However, even with this code you'll never see the drop down when you click the link.  I've modified the code in this fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dklingman/88N4A/5/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#filter').hide();


    $('body').on('click', 'nav a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#filter').toggle();
        //$('#filter').show();
        //$('#filter').children().hide();
        //$($(this).attr('href')).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I've seen that happen before, being a question I answered to some months ago actually. Most likely either copied from a Website with some type of encoding, or the writer's keyboard has foreign characters; which happened to be just that in the case of my said question I once helped out with. The blocked out characters will appear in any good IDE. +1 ;-)

Comment: That character in question, right before `</script>`, just saw it now in my IDE, being `&#8203;` which is a Zero-width space. For more information, consult http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm which most likely was done in a Word Processor.

Answer (score 0):

your css is

```
.hide{
     display:none;
}
```

your link has an id of filter

```
#filter > * {
    display:none;
}
```

that will hide all of the children of the link.

then, I would move all of your jquery to the bottom of the page just after

```
</body>
```

then start jquery with

```
$(document).ready(function(){


//do stuff here

});
</html>
```

UPDATE:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CgT93/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#filter', function(){ 
    $(this).children().show(); 
});
```

Comment: I tried what you said, it hides everything that i wanted but when i click on it, it still doesn't work :/

Comment: for sure! $(document).on('click', '#filter', function(){
$(this).children().show();
});

Comment: using .slideToggle() instead of .show() might be a better option though, that way you can click it to show them or hide them